# How can I validate a template in golang without trying to store?

Tags: go, go-templates

Let's say I am trying to read and store templates from a data source,
But there are few bad templates:

eg:  a good golang template -
`"Paid {{.AMOUNT}} to {{.PERSON}}"`

vs: bad -
`"Paid {{.AMOUNT}} to {.PERSON"`

Before storing I want to check if its a valid golang template.
Is there anyway I can do it, without actually trying to render them?

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to store it at all. Just parse it, and see if you get an error, no?

Comment: Your "bad" template is valid.

Comment: @Flimzy I am trying to store templates in my database so that messages can be rendered by just providing a map of relevant variables.

Answer (score 5):

You may parse the text of the template to check if it's syntactically correct. To do that:

```
func valid(s string) bool {
    _, err := template.New("").Parse(s)
    return err == nil
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(valid(`Paid {{.AMOUNT}} to {{.PERSON}}`))
fmt.Println(valid(`{{`))
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QEVnHHk1uBp)):

```
true
false
```

Note that this of course does not mean that you won't get an error when you try to execute the template. That also depends on what parameter you pass to the execution of course.

Also note that your second template `"Paid {{.AMOUNT}} to {.PERSON"` is syntactically correct. Using a single curly brace `{` is not an error, it will be added to the output.